# Are questions about a sentence read in a book, for which the context is not clearly described, always acceptable?

Tags: discussion, questions

I take as example [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5561/what-does-guard-mean-in-this-situation), but this question is more about that kind of questions than that specific question.

The OP is asking for the meaning of a word he found reading a book, saying that he is unsure about two meanings the word could have, but he didn't describe where the action is happening. It is true that the quoted sentence contains "platform nine and three-quarters" and a platform is normally part of a train station, but the book could have previously made clear that "platform nine and three-quarters" is the name the protagonists given to a different place.

In this case, the very next sentence would have made clear where the protagonist is:

> Getting desperate, Harry asked for the train that left at eleven o'clock, but the guard said there wasn't one.

If the doubt the user had was what *guard* means when used for somebody who works at a train station, the question should have been "When talking of people working at a train station, what does *guard* mean?" As it is now, the question is simply "What does *guard* mean in this sentence taken from *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone*?"

Are those questions acceptable? In the case they are acceptable, what should be said in the answer? Should the answer quote the part of the book that makes clear what the answer is, if the answer depends from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that in questions such as this, the OP must include that context (either by quoting the previous sentence, as you did, or by stating that the character is at the train station). Clearly the OP knew so, because one of the suggestions they made was of a train guard. So this is important contextual information that needs to be included in the question.  Otherwise the OP is unlikely to get constructive answers; luckily Harry Potter is popular enough that in this case some users had the knowledge, but that can never be assumed. So this is important context that needs to be a part of the question in order for the question to be constructive; otherwise it's a guessing game and the question is difficult to answer.

If I were to ask:

> "He heard sirens in the distance."
>
> Where are the sirens coming from?

No one has any way to answer this question, the sirens could be from any number of things!  But if I add the previous sentence as context:

> "The house was caught in a huge blaze of flames. He heard sirens in the distance."

Well now you can make an educated guess that the sirens are coming from fire trucks.

So yes, this information is definitely important to be in the question!

Comment: I think it is similar to when the OP asks if a phrase is correct, and doesn't say why he thinks it is not correct. In the specific question, the OP chose just two of the meanings of _guard_ but he didn't explain why he had doubts just about those two definitions. If then the question is reduced to "I am not sure if somebody speaking of a guard is referring to a police officer or somebody that works in a train station." then I guess we can just educated guesses.

Comment: Speaking of questions for which the answer can be given only after reading a book, what are your general thoughts? Do you think they are acceptable, or should they be avoided because the site is about English, and not about fantasy books?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Hmm... I think this is something to be determined on a case-by-case basis. In this case the OP asked the question in good faith, I think, though I'm still of the opinion that you had to have context to have any idea what was going on. (I'd have never guessed a train station if I weren't familiar with Harry Potter.) The core of the question is: "In this sentence, which of these two definitions apply?" Were we not quoting from a book, we would be okay with this question. Since one of the definitions the OP chose was train-related, clearly the OP knew that the location was (cont'd)

Comment: important to the question... So in that case you'd think they would have included the relevant information. I don't know. I think the information should be included but the question itself was asked in good faith and is in fact an English question. In this particular case it also requires a knowledge of British culture and usages, as even knowing the location I wasn't aware of the information FumbleFingers mentions, but... I think the question itself was okay. Maybe if we get a larger sample base of questions like this one, we can reevaluate?

Answer (score 5):

Actually, speaking as a Brit, I don't think either of the answers to the linked question are exactly correct. So far as I'm concerned, in BrE, in such contexts, a *guard* is ***anyone*** in uniform working at the station.

I haven't read the book, but I'm sure from JK Rowling's point of view, *guards* would include, for example, ticket inspectors, porters, signalmen, and other "platform staff". For most purposes, the general travelling public neither know nor care exactly what the man's "official" job title is - he's just part of the railway staff.

I've added the [british-english](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/british-english) tag to the question, but apart from that I see nothing wrong with it as asked.

---

OP's broader issue seems to be asking how ELL should treat questions that fail to give adequate context. I don't think the *guards* question is particularly guilty in that respect - firstly because most people who could answer it probably wouldn't *need* any more context than was provided; secondly because it's an excerpt from an extremely popular and well-known book (so it should be easy to access more of the surrounding text).

But *as a general principle*, if a question fails to give enough context for *anyone* to provide a single unambiguous answer, it should be closed as Not Constructive or Not A Real Question. ***After*** the problem has been explicitly pointed out in comments, and the OP given a reasonable amount of time to respond.

Comment: The problem is that in the quoted text there isn't any reference to where the action is taking place. I could be outside a train station, and ask to a guard where a place is. If I didn't read the book, I don't know what _guard_ means; I can guess, what I cannot say for sure.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Even if they *have* read the book, non-Brits in general probably won't be aware that for most of Rowling's original target readership, ***all*** uniformed platform staff at a train station are "guards". You seem to be objecting to the question on the grounds that you personally aren't familiar with the usage, weren't able to "look it up", and thus weren't able to answer. It's not the questioner's fault that they didn't know to include the British-English tag, but *a passing guard* and *platform nine and three-quarters* would be quite enough context for any Brit.

Comment: I object the question on the basis that _passing guard_ doesn't mean "somebody who works at the train station"; since it's a fantasy book, _platform nine and three-quarters_ doesn't necessarily means the platform of a train station. I could be not familiar with the usage, but I can read about the usage in a dictionary.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It's not a requirement of ELL questions that *everyone* (including specifically, non-native speakers) should find it easy to establish the correct answer given sufficient context and reference books. Since you obviously *didn't* know either the context or the exact meaning, I don't really see why you went to the trouble of posting your "guess" as an answer. And having done so, you now seem to want to object to the question itself. You should have just left it alone in the first place. I might then have answered it (more accurately, I think) myself.

Comment: I didn't post any guess. Read what I wrote in this question: In [another question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5563/what-does-ask-for-mean-in-this-case), the user quoted the same sentences, to which added "Getting desperate, Harry **asked for the train** that left at eleven o'clock, but the guard said there wasn't one." If my answer is a guess, then everybody's answer is a guess.

Comment: Furthermore, I started the question with, "I take as example [this question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5561/what-does-guard-mean-in-this-situation), but the question is more about that kind of questions than that specific question." This answer is focused just on that question.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Yes, my original answer did only deal with the one example. But it did specifically say that *I haven't read the book* - yet I know exactly what Rowling meant/expected to be understood by her words. Illustrating the general point that whereas *you* might have gained better insight from reading a preceding sentence or two (possibly), that's primarily a consequence of your lack of familiarity with *guards* in the context of *platforms*, not an attribute of the question as such. *(**And** I'd already edited to address the general case three hours before you said I hadn't! :)*

Comment: The user who asked that question didn't ask "When speaking of people working at a train station, what does guard mean?" He asked "What does _guard_ mean in this sentence I found on _Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone_?" Without reading that book, can you surely affirm the book doesn't contain a sentence similar to "We called that place 'platform nine and three-quarters' because it reminded us of a train station." and then "platform nine and three-quarters" is used to refer to that place? This has nothing to share with my lack of familiarity with _guards_.

Comment: Also, where do you read that somebody cannot answer a question, and then ask on the meta site if similar questions are acceptable (or vice versa, ask on the meta site and then answer the question)? Since this question is not focused on that question, what do you see wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I don't mind such questions being asked when:

- (a) the word is put in a context (preferably, at least a paragraph), and
- (b) some preliminary research has been conducted and is being shared.

In this case, the O.P. did both of those things.

As for this comment:

> Should the answer quote the part of the book that makes clear what the answer is...

Absolutely! However, I don't think that the quote makes the answer "clear." (It may help make it clear to most of us, but it obviously *isn't* clear to the O.P.; otherwise, why would the question still be asked?)

Comment: Actually, the user forgot to mention where the action is taking place; he then quoted "Getting desperate, Harry asked for the train that left at eleven o'clock, but the guard said there wasn't one." in another question. I would guess the book says where the action is taking place, or where the protagonist is going to go; it is not that all in a sudden the protagonist find himself at a train station.

Answer (score 1):

I must dissent from WendiKidd's very reasonable answer.

In the first place, I think it may be taken for granted, without further specification, that the context is a train station -- certainly the two people who answered recognized that.

In the second place, I don't think that that context is sufficient to assure that the meaning is unambiguous.

If you come from a culture which does *not* call train conductors "guards" (my own, for instance), it seems to me entirely reasonable to wonder whether everybody in a railroad called a "guard" must be a conductor -- particularly somebody encountered on the platform, not inside a car, and particularly in these days when train stations and airports are swarming with security officers who might equally be called "guards".

I note that the accepted Answer appears to acknowledge this as a source of ambiguity, since it adds that the guard/conductor in question is "obviously in this case one who is not currently on a train."

Comment: To say it all, I recognized it was a train station because another question asked from the the same user. Otherwise, I would not have understood where the action was taking place.

Comment: Anyway, this answer is focusing on just that question, when I was asking about questions where the answer is given in the book, between one of those sentences the user didn't quote in the question. I really hope nobody is going to ask about something read in _The Hobbit_.